# How to prefill date in google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to pre fill the date in google form. so It will put the date of the day it filled as default.

I tried using the TODAY() function in google sheets . so i change the url to get the date from cell in google sheets . works for everything except the Date..

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf7cdT34eHp-GXagq3DsnxX1MD_c-G6lbF6yFWOMnUvtPYUUQ/viewform?entry.178275308=**&A6&**
```

Any idea how can i do it in the simplest way?

Comment: How are you prefilling this - via URL or script?

Comment: @ross i tried via URL , i'm open to script as well if it's simpler

Comment: Include everything you've tried in the question itself - what are you passing to the URL to try to achieve this?

Comment: @ross I edit the post. you can see in the end of the URL i put the cell i want to take the information from . works for everything except the date.

Comment: Is this URL in a cell in your sheet? Are you using Excel or Google Sheets?

Comment: @ross I'm using google form and google sheets. i found on google that i can get pre fill info for google form from google sheets . it works great for other things but not on the date option. i'm looking for better way

Comment: Why do you need to put the date into the form? When you access the form responses from the Spreadsheet where they are automatically saved, there will be a time stamp correlated to each response. Tell me if this helps!

Comment: @ziganotschka i want to use google form as a place work a worker will fill a report . so i need the to put the day if filled as the default date. it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

### Deploy your script as a Web App

- Publish your Apps Script as a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and provide the URL of the web deployment to the users
- Write your code inside a `doGet()` function, so it gets evaluated every time a user open the link
- Get the current date with `new Date()` and pass it as an `itemResponse` to a [prefilled Form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#withItemResponse(ItemResponse))
- Create a redirection to the [URL to the prefilled form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#toPrefilledUrl()) with the Java Script method [`window.top.location.href`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp) inside of `<script> </script>` tags and return it with [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)

```
// will be automatically run every time the user opens the URL of the web deployment
function doGet(){
  //open your form
  var form = FormApp.openById('1Zs5Wo0wS9esNkcq8ztOZmQs3f5NrO7hgJ_0fYk262z4');
  //get the questions
  var questions = form.getItems();
  //get the question where you want to prefill the date as an answer, e.g. first question
  var question1=questions[0];
  //get the current date
  var time=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "dd-MM-yyyy");
  // prefill form with current date
  var prefilledTime=form.createResponse().withItemResponse(question1.asTextItem().createResponse(time));  
 // Get the link to the prefilled form
  var URL=prefilledTime.toPrefilledUrl();
 // redirect to the prefilled form URL dynamically created above 
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<script>window.top.location.href=\"" + URL + "\";</script>");
}
```

Comment: I kept getting an error until I used `asDateItem` from the other answer (instead of `asTextItem`).

Comment: It also showed up as a blank page until I replaced the last line with this `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<iframe src=\"" + URL + "\" width=\"640\" height=\"1734\" frameborder=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\">Loading…</iframe>");`

Answer (score 1):

I took the code from ziganotschka as base, but I had to make some changes, maybe it helps somebody:

```
function doGet(){
  //open your form open by URL
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1M-zgHyDOz2ob5StkwIoDCShJ9tePw-I5TGhdx/prefill')
  //get the questions
  var questions = form.getItems();
  //get the question where you want to prefill the date as an answer, e.g. first question
  var question1=questions[0];
  //get the current date
  var time=new Date();
  // prefill form with current date
  var prefilledTime=form.createResponse().withItemResponse(question1.asDateItem().createResponse(time));  
  // Get the link to the prefilled form
  var URL=prefilledTime.toPrefilledUrl();
  // redirect to the prefilled form URL dynamically created above 
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<script>window.top.location.href=\"" + URL + "\";</script>");
}
```

And when you're done, don't forget to *Publish ->  Deploy as a Web App...*

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the date the Form is submitted, Google Forms provides this automatically in it's Timestamp.

If you want to pre-fill a date from an existing spreadsheet, then provided you obey Google's date-format, you can use the URL approach (months & days must be 2 digits i.e. "01" not "1").

```
=substitute('Sheet_with_Form_Link'!$A$1,"2099-01-01",text(Sheet_with_date!A1,"yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

Where
Sheet_with_Form_Link'!$A$1 is a cell in a Sheet in a Google SpreadSheet containing the URL obtained via 'Get Prefilled Link'
"2099-01-01" is the data you Pre-filled into the Form whilst using 'Get Pre-filled Link'
Sheet_with_date!A1 is a cell in a Sheet in a Google SpreadSheet containing your desired date e.g. one of

```
=today()
1920/03/26
17Oct2002
```